# Global array not appending

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift development and I am working on a friend's project for more practice that deals with global variables and arrays (that has been my weak point so far). The idea is to pass the information from the selected tableview row with a timestamp to an array and then print the array on another tableview on a different view controller.

I have tried using a struct and a global variable just below UIKit and above my class to access it across all view controllers.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dopText = indexPath.item
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = ("HH:mm")
    let stamp = formatter.string(from: Date())
    interventions.append("\(stamp) Dog is in the contest \(dopDose[dopText])")
```

This is the function that calls the item to be printed to the next screen

```
["11:30 Golden Retriever entered the contest."]
["11:30 Golden Retriever entered the contest."]
["11:30 Golden Retriever entered the contest."]
```

This prints out in the debug area when navigating to that view controller

```
import UIKit

var interventions:[String] = []

class InterventionsPerformedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

This is where I have listed the global variable. I have also used a struct to make the variable(as seen below) with the same results

```
struct globalInterventions{
    static var interventions = [String]()
}
```

I am sorry if I am going about this the wrong way. I am new to coding and Swift. Any suggestions are welcome. I don't want to change his source code completely but anything that would benefit I welcome the advice.

The only thing that happens is the first time the tableview cell is selected the item is added to the array and printed on the next screen but it prints in the debug area 3 times in a row and then no other items can be added to the array.

Comment: The first and most important suggestion is not to use global properties or functions. Study OOP and why encapsulation matters.

Comment: not enough code to find your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singletons in swift should have a private initializer so no one can create an instance other than the single shared instance.  The single instance is usually called `shared`.  If you want the value to print every time you append an item then you should use a `didSet`:

```
struct Interventions {
    static var shared: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            shared.forEach{print($0)}
        }
    }
    private init() { }
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense, so with the .foreach command it would just append that new element to the same array correct?

Comment: I corrected this in my code and it is still doing the same thing. It runs fine but when I tap the button that appends to the array it prints the array item, which I have told it to do, and then prints the count of the array, which I have told it to do, but it prints the count 3 separate times in the debug area and then each time an item is added to the array it prints the entire array twice but nothing is returned to the tableview that the array is to be populated on in the final view controller.

Comment: if you want the tableview to reload you also need to put tableView.reloadData() in the didSet block, or since its a singleton that could be used by many VC's post a notification in didSet and subscribe tot he notification in all the VC's that should be interested and call reload there.

Comment: Ok awesome, I am going to get to work on the Notification Center implementation, thank you very much for all the help so far. I'll let you know how it works!

Comment: One thing I have been thinking with implementing Notification Center, would it be better to pass data with it instead of using a struct and global array?